# TortoiseHG stop credentials prompt

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm trying to stop tortoiseHG from prompting me for credentials every time i do something. I can't seem to find out how to fix this.  From what I've read you need to specify username and enable mercurial_keyring?

My mercurial.ini file

```
[ui]
username=myFirstName myLastName myFirstName.myLastName@somecompany.com

[auth]
servername.prefix = servername
servername.username = myFirstName myLastName myFirstName.myLastName@somecompany.com
servername.schemes = https://servername.somecompany.com/fogbugz/kiln

[extensions]
mercurial_keyring=
```

I have updated global settings; surely I do not need to add settings for *every* repository that I add?

Comment: Is you credentials login really 'myFirstName myLastName'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mercurial.ini:

```
[auth]
servername.prefix = servername
servername.username = login
```

You should specify your login as username, not your Mercurial's display name.

UPD: The display name (specified in `[ui]` section) is used when you commit changes. It's written into the changeset and becomes a part of history.

The name used for authentication (login) is specified in `[auth]` section. This is what you have to type in (along with password) every time when keyring doesn't work properly.

Comment: username format needs to be firstname lastname <firstname.lastname@company.com> i read?

Comment: and what about enabling the keyring is it just             [extensions]
mercurial_keyring= ? as above?

Comment: The 'firsname lastname <email>' format is recommended, yes, but it's a name that is displayed in commits, and it is specified in [ui] section. But for mercurial_keyring to work, you should specify your authentication name (i.e. login with that you push or pull) in [auth] section. I suppose you log into remote repository with some shorter login name. And yes, `mercurial_keyring=` is enough for modern Mercurial distributions (you can also enable mercurial_keyring in TortoiseHG interface).

Comment: do i need to update existing repositories or does it inherit from global settings?

Comment: i'm still getting prompted... under auth i set my actual username not including email, and ui has username and email...

Comment: Have you restarted TortoiseHG after enabling mercurial_keyring? Did you specify servername correctly? Is it the name of server where are you pulling from/pushing to? Are you being prompted for password only, or for username to? What does `hg outgoing` asks/prints? And also, have you placed `mercurial.ini` correctly? Where have you put it to?